# Use network charge to import files PST in Office 365 - unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: migration, office365, azure-blob-storage

I am using a network charge to import files PST in Office 365 follow this link:

https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Usar-la-carga-en-la-red-para-importar-archivos-PST-en-Office-365-103f940c-0468-4e1a-b527-cc8ad13a5ea6?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES

The transfer start, but in the end display (for the detail in every mailbox) the next:

- > "The transfer failed: Unable to connect to the remote server"
- > "The transfer failed: Unable to write data to the transport
  > connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
  > host"

I have a user administrator and a file shared with all Access: to read and write, I don't know if I need something special permission or disable something service?

Please your help!

Answer (score 0):

> "The transfer failed: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

The error is often caused by following 2 reasons.

1. Azure storage request either using http or https. That means it send requests through ports 80 or 443. So you need to make sure these ports are open to the internet.
2. Please double check whether you used a proxy on your machine. If yes, you need to disable the proxy or create a configuration file named 'AzCopy.exe.config' to the following location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\'.

In this file you will need to add the following XML:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <!--PROXY_ADDRESS: Is the proxy address used to connect to the internet, e.g. myproxy.company.com
      PORT_NUMBER: Is the port number used to connect to the proxy, e.g. 8080-->
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://PROXY_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER" bypassonlocal="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```